# How to format a date while printing in rml or in openoffice report?

Tags: odoo

Can anyone tell me how to print a date in a desired format in openerp reports. I use both rml and openoffice for reporting

**Default Date format in form**

```
 12/06/2013
```

**Default Date format while printing in reports**

```
 2013/06/12
```

**My Desired Format**

```
 12-June-2013
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Write following code in report py:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

'get_my_date': self.get_my_date, #Add this line in self.localcontext.update dictionary

def get_my_date(self, date):
    return time.strftime('%d') + '-' + datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y').strftime('%b') + '-' + time.strftime('%Y')
```

Call this method from your rml file:

```
<para style="P2"> [[ get_my_date(your_date) ]] </para>
```

Answer (score 0):

To print date with month in letters you have just to use `%B`.

```
<para style="terp_default_9">[[ time.strftime('%d-%B-%Y') ]] </para>
```

You can change `Date format` from `settings>Languages(you language)>Date Format`.
By default date format is `%m/%d/%Y`, change it to `%d-%B-%Y`

To print the date in you languge use `formatLang`:

```
formatLang(o.date, date=True)
```